# Best Class to Hold Fixed Amount of Data in C#

Tags: c#

Lets assume I have plenty of strings that need processing, I like to place the last processed string in memory to avoid repeated processing against it. I only need to record the last 100 strings, which means if I use

`List<string> oldString` after `oldString.Add()`, I have to use `oldString.TakeFromEnd(100)` As you know, `TakeFromEnd()` not exist, which means if I go this path, I have to write lots of things to keep a 100 length `List` which would lead to bad performance I can imagine.

I'd like to ask, is there any pre-made in system Class that just holds a fixed amount of data, and throws away oldest data when a new one is added. Thanks

**[EDIT]**

`Queue<string>` is very good indeed, use `.Any()` to check if already exist, use `.Enqueue()` to add *(not Equeue as answered below, it shot a N)*, use `.Count` to check length, and `.Dequeue()` to remove the first added one.

Comment: Do you need access to all 100 stored strings or is it enough for the storage mechanism to provide only the single earliest stored string?

Comment: No, I do not need to access all 100 strings, but I need to compare with them. E.g use linq to `.Exist()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Work with a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx)

And the idea is to:

```
public void addToQueue(Object obj){
    if (myQueue.Count > 100)
        myQueue.Dequeue();

    myQueue.Equeue(obj);
}
```

This is roughly a sketch of the code that you need to use, but you`ll get the idea.

You will then have a queue than contains only the latest 100 records

Comment: The relevant methods of Queue are called `Dequeue` and `Enqueue` not `pop` and `push`. Also I don't believe Queue has a mechanism to allow you to access any element except for the one at the head of the queue (i.e. the earliest 'pushed' element). This may not fully solve the problem.

Comment: That's why I mentioned it's a sketch (-: I`ve updated the answer

Comment: You should probably look at the generic type of Queue<T>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch, queues are based on a first in first out mechanism which ensures it`ll contain the *latest* 100 (or n) elements... what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: @joshuam Yes, the generic Queue provides random access to individual elements (via ElementAt) so may be a better functional fit too.

Comment: @Shai I agree that this mechanism works in terms of holding the last 100 elements I'm just not sure that it solves the complete need since I'm assuming access is required to all 100 elements. I'll ask the OP the question directly.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch it depends whether he`s interested in direct access, good point though

Comment: @Shai @MatthewMurdoch I do not need direct access (read), but I do need to compare with them to know if it has been done. So a LINQ `.Exist()` will fit my needs.